# How can the total torque of a body equal a "torque" at only one point?

Tags: rigid-body-dynamics, solid-mechanics

I am trying to understand the solution to this problem.
[image]

Pictured is a rough sketch of a ball in which another, smaller ball of density $\rho_2 > \rho_1$, where $\rho_1$ is the density of the larger ball, is contained. The ball is oscillating, as it is currently out of balance.

Two forces act on the ball: friction $F_r$ and gravity $F_g$. The problem is to find the angular acceleration of the ball at that moment. So, it seems that one can set up these equations:

$I\alpha = -F_gd\sin{\theta} - F_rR$

where $R$ is the radius of the ball and $d$ is the distance to the center of mass from its geometrical center. Both are unimportant to the question. Now, the attached solution I'm reading claims the following:

The point T, which is the contact point between the ball and the ground, experiences an angular acceleration given by $I\alpha = F_rR$ and, as the ball is rigid, that acceleration is equal to the angular acceleration of the entire ball. Combining the equations one can get: $\alpha = \frac{mg\sin{\theta}}{2I}$.

This last paragraph is completely unclear to me. I agree that the acceleration of the point is equal to the acceleration of the rest of the ball, but I don't understand at all how it can be calculated as if other forces don't act on the point. Doesn't the point experience attraction from the other points of the ball around it? If not, what's keeping the ball rigid? Also, how can't this logic be used to circumvent the calculation of the friction force in practically all dynamics problems? This is the first and only time I've seen it employed.

I'd appreciate any explanation of this reasoning. Thank you.